# How to stub a method of jasmine mock object?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

According to the Jasmine documentation, a mock can be created like this:

```
jasmine.createSpyObj(someObject, ['method1', 'method2', ... ]);
```

How do you stub one of these methods? For example, if you want to test what happens when a method throws an exception, how would you do that?

Comment: You can try to chain it with `andCallThrough`. It isnt clearly documented :/

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You have to chain `method1`, `method2` as EricG commented, but not with `andCallThrough()` (or `and.callThrough()` in version 2.0). It will *delegate to real implementation*.

In this case you need to chain with `and.callFake()` and pass the function you want to be called (can throw exception or whatever you want):

```
var someObject = jasmine.createSpyObj('someObject', [ 'method1', 'method2' ]);
someObject.method1.and.callFake(function() {
    throw 'an-exception';
});
```

And then you can verify:

```
expect(yourFncCallingMethod1).toThrow('an-exception');
```

Comment: Jasmine 2.0 has changed the syntax to `.and.callFake()`, `.and.callThrough()`, `.and.returnValue()` http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Answer (score 26):

If you are using Typescript, it's helpful to cast the method as `Jasmine.Spy`. In the above Answer (oddly I don't have rep for comment):

```
(someObject.method1 as Jasmine.Spy).and.callFake(function() {
  throw 'an-exception';
});
```

I don't know if I'm over-engineering, because I lack the knowledge...

For Typescript, I want:

- Intellisense from the underlying type
- The ability to mock just the methods used in a function

I've found this useful:

```
namespace Services {
    class LogService {
        info(message: string, ...optionalParams: any[]) {
            if (optionalParams && optionalParams.length > 0) {
                console.log(message, optionalParams);
                return;
            }

            console.log(message);
        }
    }
}

class ExampleSystemUnderTest {
    constructor(private log: Services.LogService) {
    }

    doIt() {
        this.log.info('done');
    }
}

// I export this in a common test file 
// with other utils that all tests import
const asSpy = f => <jasmine.Spy>f;

describe('SomeTest', () => {
    let log: Services.LogService;
    let sut: ExampleSystemUnderTest;

    // ARRANGE
    beforeEach(() => {
        log = jasmine.createSpyObj('log', ['info', 'error']);
        sut = new ExampleSystemUnderTest(log);
    });

    it('should do', () => {
        // ACT
        sut.doIt();

        // ASSERT
        expect(asSpy(log.error)).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(asSpy(log.info)).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(asSpy(log.info).calls.allArgs()).toEqual([
            ['done']
        ]);
    });
});
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't compile for me (jasmine 2.5) but this solution worked!

Comment: Mini-improvement - `todoService: {[key: string]: jasmine.Spy} = jasmine.createSpyObj(...); todoService.anyMethod.and....` - no need to cast to Spy every time.

Comment: Thanks @Kai, I added some detail. I needed (wanted?) type recognition as the primary type rather than as a dynamic Spy object. I personally wanted the object to act and feel like the real object and then only cast to Spy when I was testing.

Answer (score 11):

**Angular 9**

Using `jasmine.createSpyObj` is ideal when testing a component where a simple service is injected. For example: let's say, in my HomeComponent I have a HomeService (injected). The only method in the HomeService is getAddress(). 
When creating the HomeComponent test suite, I can initialize the component and service as:

```
describe('Home Component', () => {
    let component: HomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeComponent>;
    let element: DebugElement;
    let homeServiceSpy: any;
    let homeService: any;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        homeServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HomeService', ['getAddress']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           declarations: [HomeComponent],
           providers: [{ provide: HomeService, useValue: homeServiceSpy }]
        })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            element = fixture.debugElement;
            homeService = TestBed.get(HomeService);
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
    }));

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should display home address", () => { 
        homeService.getAddress.and.returnValue(of('1221 Hub Street'));
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const address = element.queryAll(By.css(".address"));

        expect(address[0].nativeNode.innerText).toEqual('1221 Hub Street');
    });
 });
```

This is a simple way to test your component using `jasmine.createSpyObj`. However, if your service has more methods more complex logic, I would recommend creating a mockService instead of createSpyObj. For example:
`providers: [{ provide: HomeService, useValue: MockHomeService }]`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Eric Swanson's answer, I've created a better readable and documented function for using in my tests. I also added some type safety by typing the parameter as a function.

I would recommend to place this code somewhere in a common test class, so that you can import it in every test file that needs it.

```
/**
 * Transforms the given method into a jasmine spy so that jasmine functions
 * can be called on this method without Typescript throwing an error
 *
 * @example
 * `asSpy(translator.getDefaultLang).and.returnValue(null);`
 * is equal to
 * `(translator.getDefaultLang as jasmine.Spy).and.returnValue(null);`
 *
 * This function will be mostly used in combination with `jasmine.createSpyObj`, when you want
 * to add custom behavior to a by jasmine created method
 * @example
 * `const translator: TranslateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TranslateService', ['getDefaultLang'])
 * asSpy(translator.getDefaultLang).and.returnValue(null);`
 *
 * @param {() => any} method - The method that should be types as a jasmine Spy
 * @returns {jasmine.Spy} - The newly typed method
 */
export function asSpy(method: () => any): jasmine.Spy {
  return method as jasmine.Spy;
}
```

Usage would be as follows:

```
import {asSpy} from "location/to/the/method";

const translator: TranslateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('TranslateService', ['getDefaultLang']);
asSpy(translator.getDefaultLang).and.returnValue(null);
```