# Angular Jasmine - override one property of service while keeping other methods/properties

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have an Angular service which has as private member a class instance (Keycloak). The class is defined in an external npm library (keycloak-js). In the constructor of the service, I call keycloak.init() which makes some HTTP requests. When writing unit tests for the service, I want to avoid calling the real keycloak.init function. All other methods/properties of the service should remain the original ones. Here is some minimal code:

```
//defined in external npm library
export class Keycloak {
  init() {
    //makes HTTP calls
    console.log('Obj func');
  }
}
```

---

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class KeycloakService{
  private keycloak;
  constructor() {
    this.keycloak = new Keycloak();
    this.keycloak.init();
  }
  //other methods and props
}
```

---

```
describe('KeycloakService', () => {
  let service: KeycloakService;
  const objectSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<Keycloak> = jasmine.createSpyObj('Keycloak', [
    'init',
  ]);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [KeycloakService],
      //somehow override KeycloakService.keycloak with keycloakSpy, while keeping other methods and properties untouched
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(KeycloakService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How could I achieve this?

**Update:**
I'm managed to solve the problem by wrapping the Keycloak class into an Angular service, but I still wonder if this can be avoided. Updated complete code:

```
//defined in external npm library
export class Keycloak {
  init() {
    //makes HTTP calls
    console.log('Obj func');
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class KeycloakWrapper extends Keycloak {}
```

---

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class KeycloakService {
  constructor(private keycloak: KeycloakWrapper) {}
  //other methods and props
}
```

---

```
describe('KeycloakService', () => {
  let service: KeycloakService;
  const keycloakSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<KeycloakWrapper> = jasmine.createSpyObj(
    'KeycloakWrapper',
    ['init']
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        KeycloakService,
        { provide: KeycloakWrapper, useValue: keycloakSpy },
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(KeycloakService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stub a method of jasmine mock object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642884/how-to-stub-a-method-of-jasmine-mock-object)

Comment: No, not really. I'm testing the KeycloakService, so I don't want to completely replace it with a mock object.  I only want to avoid keycloak.init being called in its constructor. Now if the 'Keycloak' class would have also been an angular service, I could have used a spy to stub its methods, when testing KeycloakService.

Comment: I would suggest mocking all dependencies in unit tests. But if you want to use the real service, you can just spy on the init method and mock its implementation as described in the link.

Comment: Yes I'd like to mock the dependencies(Keycloak), but the problem is that that's a class from a non Angular npm library. So it's not an Angular service. I have managed to solve my issue (see update), by simply wrapping Keycloak into an Angular service, but I still wonder if this can be avoided.

Comment: To avoid the wrapper class, you can use [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) and provide it via `useClass` in your regular code, and via `useValue` with the mock object in the test.

Comment: I found a solution using Inject and Optional. Is it also correct, or should I rather try with InjectionToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, using @Inject and @Optional:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class KeycloakService {
  constructor(@Inject(Keycloak) @Optional() private keycloak?: Keycloak) {
    this.keycloak = keycloak || new Keycloak();
    this.keycloak.init();
  }
  //other methods and props
}
```

---

```
describe('KeycloakService', () => {
  let service: KeycloakService;
  const keycloakSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<Keycloak> = jasmine.createSpyObj(
    'Keycloak',
    ['init']
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: Keycloak, useValue: keycloakSpy },
        KeycloakService,
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(KeycloakService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```